# How to get a file list as utf8 encoded string into gnuplot?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, encoding, utf-8

I need the file list of a directory as `utf8` encoded string in gnuplot.

In gnuplot you can make a system call via `system()`, which (to my limited understanding) just calls `cmd.exe` and will carry out the string argument as command and returns the output (stdout) from the system call. In the following, I'm talking only about Windows.

*Example 1:*  `FILES = system('dir /b')`

This will open a Windows console and shows the file list in the current directory. The console will be closed afterwards.
The gnuplot variable `FILES` will contain the filenames as string as they were given on the console.
However, this string will not correctly represent characters like `ä,ö,ü,ß,é,à,ñ,Ä,Ö,Ü,...`
What I need is the file list as `utf8` encoded string.

Furthermore, there is another gnuplot command `load '< '`, which will redirect content to gnuplot.

*Example 2:*
`load '< echo $Data ^<^<EOD & type "myFile.txt"'`

This will write `$Data <<EOD` to gnuplot followed by the content of the file `myFile.txt`, i.e. the gnuplot datablock named `$Data` will contain the content of the file.

**My goal:**

In order to achieve my goal to get the filenames of a directory into a `utf8` encoded string, I have come only this far:

1. make a system call and change the codepage to 65001 (utf8) and redirect the directory in a temporary file, e.g. `Temp.txt`

   `system('chcp 65001 && cmd.exe /c dir /b "Test\*.dat" > "Temp.txt"')`
2. load the temporary file `Temp.txt` into gnuplot.

   `load '< echo $Data ^<^<EOD & type "Temp.txt"'`

This works somehow, however, I don't want to use a detour via a temporary file on disk (see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65272771/7295599)
I have tried many variations, e.g. with several `cmd.exe` instances or something like `>&1`, etc. but I haven't found yet a combination which would be a satisfying solution.

Any ideas how to accomplish this under Windows without the use of a temporary file?

Comment: Thank you for all test and feed backs, sorry my limited english

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe thank you for your patience and endurance. I haven't found out yet how to award you a bounty. Maybe I only can give this after two days when the question was asked?! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Relax, that is ok to me. The import thing is solve this, but, maybe some more answers came and will be more efficient/secure ways for you. Who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved:

```bat
print system('<con: chcp 65001 >nul & cmd.exe /c "dir /b Test\*.dat"')
```

Comment: I guess we need to include a re-direction, maybe either `>` or `<` which will do the conversion to UTF8, what I understood from ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html But it looks like this can only be done from or to a file.

Comment: the following gives Umlauts in Windows console `dir /b "Test\*.dat" >CON`, but in gnuplot `print system('dir /b "Test\*.dat" >CON')` gives no output.

Comment: @theozh `cmd /u/c "<con: dir/b .\test\*.dat|more"`

Comment: aahh, we're getting closer :-). In gnuplot `print system('<con: chcp 65001 & cmd.exe /c "dir /b Test\*.dat"')` gives me for example: `Active code page: 65001
Perù.dat
Österreich.dat
Ελλάς.dat`. If we now could remove the `Active code page: 65001`, then it would be perfect. Thank you very much for directing me to this.

Comment: @theozh `chcp 65001 >nul ....`

Comment: Perfect: the following works for me in gnuplot: `print system('<con: chcp 65001 >nul & cmd.exe /c "dir /b Test\*.dat"')`. Could you please add this to your answer such that I can accept it and award it with a bounty?